ThingsBoard: Do not split up incoming JSON array?
I am currently experimenting with a temperature sensor. Data sent by the sensor is received by KPN Things, which will then send it to ThingsBoard (via a webhook). Such data looks like this (example taken from KPN Things documentation):
[
  {"bn": "urn:dev:DEVEUI:0123456789ABCDEF:", "bt": 1.58565075E9, 
   "n": "temperature", "v": 20.5, "u": "Cel"},
  {"n": "batteryVoltage", "v": 3.6, "u": "V", "t": 10},
  {"n": "active", "vb": true},
  {"n": "modus", "vs": "Active"},
  {"n": "image", "vd": "aGFsbG9vb29vISE="}
]

The problem is that ThingsBoard splits up this array, so we're receiving multiple "messages"; in this case, {"bn": "urn:dev:DEVEUI:0123456789ABCDEF:", "bt": 1.58565075E9, "n": "temperature", "v": 20.5, "u": "Cel"}, {"n": "batteryVoltage", "v": 3.6, "u": "V", "t": 10}, etc.
What I want is to keep the original message, turn it into one object containing all the relevant info/stats, and then continue in the rule chain with that. Is this possible? (To be clear, the problem is how to receive the original array; extracting the relevant data and creating a new object won't be an issue.)

Try to send message as json object, not array:
{
    "my_array":[
      {"bn": "urn:dev:DEVEUI:0123456789ABCDEF:", "bt": 1.58565075E9, "n": "temperature", "v": 20.5, "u": "Cel"},
      {"n": "batteryVoltage", "v": 3.6, "u": "V", "t": 10},
      {"n": "active", "vb": true},
      {"n": "modus", "vs": "Active"},
      {"n": "image", "vd": "aGFsbG9vb29vISE="}
    ]
}


An array is a valid JSON object, but in any case, I have no control over what KPN Things sends exactly, so I cannot turn it into something that looks like the above. I ended up writing a data converter in ThingsBoard.
